# how to ignore google chrome autofill off in form tag or all inputs

Tags: html, forms

How to ignore google chrome autofill or autocomplete off in form tag or all inputs tags.
I used *autocomplete off* for all inputs but, it's not working.

Please give me a solution to this problem!

Comment: That's browser settings. https://support.iclasspro.com/hc/en-us/articles/218569268-How-to-Disable-and-Clear-AutoFill-Info-in-your-Browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to turn autocomplete off, or ignore autocomplete off?

To turn it off, add to your form:

```
<form id="regForm" method="GET" action="/something" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
 $('#yourinput_id').attr("autocomplete","off");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the form Just Use :

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

And For the Inputs Use :

```
<input autocomplete="off">
```

I hope to be helpful for your question